# Ashe Q. How exactly does her new spell work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Ashe was reworked a while ago, and her Q has changed.

[Ranger's Focus:](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ashe)

> If Ashe has 5 stacks of Focus on activation, Ranger's Focus
>   will also cause each of Ashe's basic attacks to fire a flurry of five
>   arrows. Each arrow deals modified damage that stacks multiplicatively
>   with Frost Shot and benefits from life steal. The
>   flurry will trigger on-attack effects five times but on-hit effects
>   are only applied once.

- What would the **total damage** be at lvl 5 Q with 5 stacks of focus after a single flurry?
- Which on-attack effects would be useful to have and how would they apply?

I know that calculating the *exact* damage is not possible because it depends on many factors (including items, runes, masteries and mostly how long Ashe can stand still and deal damage). An approximate value however would do.

Comment: There is some sort of percentage calculation that applies to the flurry, and most people build the new cleaver on ashe because it adds the stacks so quickly with flurry.

Comment: @Greatwon From wiki: _...on-hit effects are only applied once.._ - I think they shouldn't buy BC since each flurry would apply only one stack. There is a difference between "on-hit" and "on-attack" effects.

Comment: Just did a little research and black cleaver does get proc'd 5 times - http://boards.pbe.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/champions-gameplay-feedback/6BBcWPLy-ashe-update-feedback-thread - see the 3rd Rioter post by clicking the arrows on the left hand side

Comment: @Greatwon If the rioter is indeed correct then this wiki article should be edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by ChaseC, situational damage taken by a specific target is impossible to predict due to the intervention of a variety of variables, such as buffs, debuffs and the target's armor stat. It should be fairly straightforward to figure out base damage, though.

For the sake of simplicity, I'll ignore the effects of Runes and Masteries in this answer. When talking about effects relating to the ability, it'll be the level 5 version, and champion base stats will be for level 18.

---

You've already quoted the [wiki page](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ashe) in your question, so I won't repeat that here.
Each arrow fired in the flurry of 5 arrows has damage equal to 27% of Ashe's Attack Damage (AD), meaning the entire salvo has a Physical Damage (PD) output of 135% AD.

At level 18, Ashe's base AD is 100, therefore, we can calculate the PD dealt by Ashe before resistance reductions with a very simple calculation of:

> 100 AD x 135% = 135 PD for a single flurry.

Now lets consider this with items - a typical [build for Ashe](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/ashes-to-ashes-67331) has a end-game build of *[Beserker's Greaves](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Berserker%27s_Greaves)*, *[Infinity Edge](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity_Edge)*, *[Phantom Dancer](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Phantom_Dancer)*, *[Last Whisper](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Whisper)*, *[The Bloodthirster](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bloodthirster)* and *[Banshee's Veil](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Banshee%27s_Veil)*, with an *[Elixir of Wrath](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elixir_of_Wrath)* consumable to finish things off.

Altogether, these items provide additional (relevant) stats of:

- +75% attack speed (25 BG, 50 PD)
- +225 AD (80 IE, 40 LW, 80 BT, 25 EoW)
- +55% Critical Strike Chance (20 IE, 35 PD)
- +50% Critical Strike Damage (50 IE)

With an updated AD total of 325, the total PD output of *Ranger's Focus* after being fully built is:

> 325 AD x 135% =  438.75 PD per auto-attack while *Ranger's Focus* is active.

---

In addition, Ashe's passive *Frost Shots* guarantees critical strikes on a target with the debuff *Frost*, applied by auto-attacks and certain abilities. Given the nature of *Ranger's Focus*, the target is more than likely already affected by *Frost*, giving the increased damage of:

> 110 + (Critical Strike Chance % × (1 + Bonus Critical Strike Damage)) % AD

If we input the appropriate numbers from the improved stats above, we get a calculation of:

> 110 + (55% × (150%)) = 192.5% AD

Assuming the target is already debuffed by frost, the damage taken (before armor reductions) is:

> 438.75 PD x 192.5% = **844.594 PD for a *single flurry* of 5 arrows.**

While we're here we may as well go deeper. Ashe has an attack speed of 1.224 at level 18. Including the items above, a late-game Ashe will have an attack speed of 1.974. Upon activation, *Ranger's Focus* grants a further 40% attack speed, bringing the total to 2.374.

Once triggered, the ability lasts for 4 seconds. Assuming the very first flurry is right as the ability is activated, Ashe will be able to send out:

> 4 seconds x 2.374 attack speed = 9.496, or 9 auto-attacks over the duration.

If we apply this to our original equation, we'll find the maximum damage achievable over the 4 seconds *Ranger's Focus* is active, assuming we're relying solely on auto-attacks:

> 438.75 PD x 192.5% x 9 instances of the ability = **7,601.344 PD, which is the *maximum* possible damage output of a perfectly timed *Ranger's Focus* (with this build). This comes out with a possible (physical) Damage Per Second (DPS) of 1900.336**

This is correct as of Patch 5.11.

---

As for useful items to benefit from the on-attack benefits, anything with lifesteal is a bonus. If you prefer to have a more attack speed focused build, *[Runaan's Hurricane](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Runaan%27s_Hurricane)* could be a useful pick, as it's unique passive activates for each arrow in the flurry.

Comment: Of course, dealing that much damage is near impossible. It's just a figure of what *can* be achieved given the right circumstances.

Comment: Regarding on-attack effects [this](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/On-hit_effect#On-Attack_Effects) shows Muramana as being on-attack. Do you know if it actually triggers it 5 times per flurry?

Comment: Your figures seem quite reasonable for stationary fights. A 200 armor target (not including armor reductions) would take 1/3 of that damage.

Comment: @user5061 Yes, each shot in the flurry will activate any on-attack abilities, so the Muramana's passive should activate 5 times. However, that ability has a restriction of 2 activations per 8 seconds, so it wouldn't be as powerful as it first seems. The toggled ability for consuming mana to deal bonus damage is *on-hit*, and will therefore not activate 5 times, but once.

Comment: @user5061 I've added a little bit more information before that last equation to make it a bit more understandable, and added a dps to the end as well.

Comment: Are you sure about the 235%?  My reading is that each basic attack _turns into_ a flurry, as opposed to being augmented by a flurry.  Thus I would expect 135% (5 \* 27%).

Comment: @AaronDufour You're completely right, I'll make those changes right away

Answer (score 0):

The total damage is impossible to predict because that would involve game-to-game items, runes, masteries and level.

The on-attack effects that are most useful is usually just Bloodthirster for Ashe.

Comment: This should be a comment imo